# Add on-hover effect on picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is my code:

**CSS**

```
 .obrazkii img {
            width: 25%;
            float: left;
        }
@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .entry-content {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 885px) {.obrazkii img {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }}
@media screen and (max-width: 590px) {.obrazkii img {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }}
```

**HTML**

```
            <div>
                  <div class="obrazkii">
        <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="obrazkii">
   <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="http://davehallsba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon-145444.png"></a></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4LjeL/111/

Everything work but I would like to add an extra feature. When I hover on photo I would like to show text over the photo (with animation and opacity). It should work on mobile also.. Is it even possible?

Comment: plenty of tutorials on the net -- http://alijafarian.com/jquery-image-hover-captions/

Comment: Not with the current structure that you are using

Comment: @Tasos I tried this code and it is not working.. Look at my website: http://azymut.maurycy.eu/486-2/ :( Any idea?

Comment: you have an error in the cosnole (Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function) at line 249 -- ($(document).ready(function() { -- ) so the script isnt running -- have a look here about document ready --- https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: that looks ok actually -- are you loading Jquery??

Comment: @Tasos What do You mean by loading Jquery? This website is on Wordpress (I did not use theme made by sb, I did it on my own using framework so there can be a lot of errors) and I just copied and pasted the code from the website you gave..

Comment: i just did a test and jquery does not load -- if i paste the jquery code in the console and run the hover functions it works -- you have this line in your page (<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>) -- move this line in the Head of you document

Comment: heres a screen capture -- http://s16.postimg.org/fq19jayg5/Capture.jpg

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding hover effects using CSS can be relatively easy, just use:

```
#foo: hover {}
```

and then you can define what it does on hover.

However, for things like animation and opacity as well as mobile support, it may be worthwhile looking into to JQueryUI, and plain JQuery to help you out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have a space in your solution code. Should be: `#foo:hover {}`